# What is theta value?

Tags: linear-algebra, theta-functions

Using a pre-defined formula in Desmos android app the following example is given :

[image]

What is value of theta used within formula for evaluating r ?
Is it some implicit value, as it's value is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are plotting in polar coordinates, the two independent variables are $r$ and $\theta$.
Hence the values of $\theta$ are from a range,  $-\pi$ to $\pi$, or 0 to $2\pi$.

It is like $y=2x+1$, the value of $x$ takes all real numbers, not just a single value.

Comment: thanks, what determines the specific value of theta at each point ? It's determined by the current polar co-ordinate ?

Comment: Yes it is related to the polar coordinates